# What was the rationale for adding a second namespacing operator to PHP?

Tags: php, namespaces

In PHP there are two namespacing operators:

`\` and `::`

`::` is used for internal namespacing, e.g:

```
namespace example;
class Foo {
    public static $bar = 'hello';
}
```

I can access `$bar` and other members of the `Foo` class via: `Foo::$bar`

The full namespaced name of `Foo` however is not `example::Foo`, it is `example\Foo`, and the full namespaced name of $bar would be `example\Foo::$bar`

What was the reason or rationale for using the two operators rather than sticking with one consistent operator that already existed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should take a peek at [the namespace separator RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/backslashnamespaces#use_as_namespace_separator), which calls out the actual arguments used in favor of and against the backslash.

The main reason why `::` wasn't picked was due to the possible ambiguity it caused when doing scope resolution.  Given that namespaces can be aliased (`use \Foo\Bar as Baz;`), all sorts of hilarious hijinks could be caused.

Comment: Always happy to see your awnser. Most of the time I learn something:) +1

Comment: Thanks, in C++ the ambiguity wouldn't exist because it would generate a compile time or linking error, but ofc that doesnt happen in PHP hmmm

Comment: The ambiguity only exists in PHP for two reasons: 1) `::` has been used exclusively for classes, and namespaces aren't classes, and 2) namespace aliasing.  In other languages, like Perl, classes and namespaces are identical concepts... so to speak, kinda.  Okay, given that Perl uses "package" instead of either of those terms, I expect that it isn't the best example.

Answer (score 4):

The `::` is the [Scope Resolution Operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php) and is only ment to access static classes. It has nothing to do with the namespace. Also the [namespacing](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rationale.php) has been added in PHP 5.3, so long after static classes.

I guess thats why they use two different operators (for two different goals)

Comment: The issue being that C++ uses :: for both and has no issues, why not in PHP?